# In Solr using SynonymFilterFactory to match within a title.

Tags: solr

I have a search for a term shoes that I want to match in a title field and expand with synonyms. When the user searches for shoes it should also match: hi tops, boots and sneakers. I also want to query Solr for all the documents that have shoes under the title field category, so I have a query like:

q=category:shoes

If I have this setup in synonyms.txt everything works:

shoes => shoes, boots, sneakers.

It breaks when I make the change to:

shoes => shoes, boots, sneakers, hi tops

How do I get Solr to work with a multi term word in the synonyms.txt file for searches in a title field?

Comment: For right now, I changed it so the fieldType is no longer using solr.SynonymFilterFactory in the schema. This stops it from returning no results when searching in a category and still allows it to work for a global search. I still have questions as to what is actually going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Here is all you need to know, sorry there is no short answer for this.

http://www.opensourceconnections.com/2013/10/27/why-is-multi-term-synonyms-so-hard-in-solr

Comment: Thanks for the information. I appreciate the help on working towards a solution.